# Adjacency list Graph representation

Tags: c++

Following is the graph I used to create adj list.

[image]

The code should follow all the best practices of C++ 14 and stl.

map is used instead of vector to keep label.

Any suggestions for better implementation are welcome. 
.h

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using std::unordered_map;
using std::list;
using std::pair;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::make_pair;
using std::for_each;

class AdjList
{
private:

    typedef pair<int, char> edge;
    unordered_map<char , list <edge> > adjList;

public:
    void createGraph();
    void printGraph();
    void test();
};
```

.cpp

```
#include "AdjList.h"

void AdjList::createGraph()
{
    list<edge> A;
    A.push_back(make_pair(3, 'B'));
    A.push_back(make_pair(2, 'E'));

    list<edge> B; //B points nowhere

    list<edge> C;
    C.push_back(make_pair(1, 'A'));

    list<edge> D;
    D.push_back(make_pair(4, 'C'));

    list<edge> E;
    E.push_back(make_pair(4, 'D'));

    adjList['A'] = A;
    adjList['B'] = B;
    adjList['C'] = C;
    adjList['D'] = D;
    adjList['E'] = E;

}

void AdjList::printGraph()
{
    for each (auto elem in adjList)
    {
        cout << elem.first << " -> ";

        for_each(elem.second.begin(), elem.second.end(), [](auto val) {

            cout << val.second << "(" << val.first << "), ";

        });

        cout << endl;
    }
}

void AdjList::test()
{
    createGraph();
    printGraph();
}
```

`test()` is called from main to test.

Output:

> A -> B(3), E(2),
>
> B ->
>
> C -> A(1),
>
> D -> C(4),
>
> E -> D(4),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good work!

**Do not polute the global namespace in headers**

```
using std::unordered_map;
...
```

Anyone who `#include`s your file will have these imported in their global namespace. You should should migrate these to your .cpp file, and just use `std::` for the two instances in the header.

**list<> vs vector<>**

There is nothing in your code that suggests `list<>` is preferable to `vector<>`. Unless you need fast insertion/removal in the middle of the structure, `vector<>` is preferable here.

**For each ( in ) is not a thing**

`for each (auto elem in adjList)` is not standard C++, but a MSVC extension, use range-based for instead. Furthermore, by using `auto` instead of `auto &`, you are working on **copies** of the adjacency list, not references.

You want this:

```
for(auto const& elem : adjList) {
```

**Don't use for_each when a range-based for works.**

`for_each` is not best practice unless you are already manipulating a predicate. range-based-for is preferable:

Like so:

```
for(auto const& val : elem.second) {
    cout << val.second << "(" << val.first << "), ";
}
```

**Emplace into containers**

You want to use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()` in containers where possible:

Like So:

```
list<edge> C;
C.push_back(make_pair(1, 'A')); // bad
C.emplace_back(1, 'A'); // much better
```

**Move containers if you know you are done with them.**

When you do this:

```
adjList['A'] = A;
```

You create a copy of A, when you know you are done with it. You should promote A to a RValue:

```
adjList['A'] = std::move(A);
```

**You are mixing your functionality with your test harness**

`createGraph();` and `test();` have no business being members of this class, and should be free-floating functions.

Once you do this, you will realize that there is a lot of stuff missing from your class as it does not expose the interface required to implement these simple cases.

Answer (score 2):

Same procedure as always:

- Don't use `using` in headers, at least not to modify the global namespace.
- In a header, only include those headers that are necessary for the *definitions*.

Specific to your code:

- The public API of the `AdjList` is useless, since you can only create a single graph with it.
- Instead of `AdjList`, it should be called `AdjListGraph`, since it is a graph, not a list.
- The method `add_edge(char, int, char)` would make the class useful. It would also free the calling code from using `std::pair`, which should be considered an implementation detail.
- If you can foresee that after creation, graphs will be heavily modified by removing edges, your choice of using `std::list` is good. Otherwise, prefer `std::vector`.

In the end, your code should look like this:

```
AdjListGraph g;
g.add_edge('A', 3, 'B');
g.add_edge('A', 2, 'E');
g.add_edge('C', 7, 'A');
...

std::cout << "The graph is:\n";
std::cout << g;
```